# Why node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser is not supported resolving ES modules?

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, node-modules

When I made changes to Angular code, they were no longer being reflected in the build.  Google told me to delete *node_modules* and angular and reinstall.  I did

```
rd /s node_modules
npm install
npm install --save --only=dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Now when I do `ng build`, I'm getting error

> node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser' is not
> supported resolving ES modules

If I do `ng update`, it tells me *everything seems to be in order*.

I don't understand why a local and global version of angular is needed. It causes much confusion.
Also don't know why ng build stopped updating project, nor how to fix it.  Fixes cause even more problems!  Can anyone please shed some light?